# Good extension/wrapper for mysqli that returns a associated array for a prepared sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can anyone recommend a good wrapper class or extension to PHP's mysqli extension that allows the equivalent of

mysql->fetch_assoc()

for a **prepared** statement.  That is ideally it condenses down into a single statement the tedious complexity of the init/prepare/bind/fetch-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a class that extends mysqli and adds that functionality!!!!

Here's a start

http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#72720

Answer (score 1):

try dalmp.com code.dalmp.com currently on beta but maybe you can help to test it

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP 5 class that does just that: http://www.aplweb.co.uk/blog/php/mysqli-wrapper-class/

Just put in your settings and call one of the static functions.

Answer (score -1):

It's actually really easy to write wrappers for or extend PDO.

```
$this->setAttribute(self::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('yourClassName', array($this)));
```

Something like that will let you specify a class to replace PDOStatement.

Answer (score -2):

[`Zend_DB`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) is a great wrapper for database functions including mysqli.

It has options to retrieve table data as associative arrays, or as objects if you desire.  It also includes support for prepared statements.

You don't have to use the entire zend framework to use Zend_DB, you can use it on its own.